# Differentiating entries of two types of users by a boolean attribute [Ruby on rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes

I quite new to Ruby and am building my own social network website. I have a User model in my project that has a boolean attribute x, which is assigned true or false during the sign up. This means that there are only two types of users.

There is also an Entry model. Entries belong to users. Users have many entries.

One type of users post the entries and another type of users claim the entries.

Right now every entry has a user_id attribute and a helper_id attribute, which I am seeking to change because ***I want to list the "entries posted" and "entries claimed" under the two types of users, respectively.***

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this? Many thanks!

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking here. Why are you looking to change having a `user_id` and `helper_id` in your `Entry` model? What do you mean that you _"want to list the 'entries posted' and 'entries claimed' under the two types of users, respectively"_? With your current structure, you'd already be able to do that with some variation on: `Entry.includes(:user).to_a.group_by{|e|e.user.x}`

Answer (score 0):

Use STI- single table inheritance for user model.

```
Class User
end

class UserTypeA < User
  has_many :entries, foreign_key: :user_id
end

class UserTypeB < User
  has_many :entries, foreign_key: :helper_id
end
```

And make a `type` column as string in the users table.

Now to get the claimed entries call `userB.entries` and get posted entries call `userA.entries`

Comment: Thanks very much! Should I change anything in the users_controller? currently there's a boolean column in the users table which returns true if the user is typeA and returns false if the user is typeB

Comment: You can use `user.kind_of? UserTypeA` instead of boolean column

Comment: Sorry if I am not getting this. Where should I use user.kind_of? ?

Comment: The place where u r using the boolean column to differentiate. I would recommend to read on STI and its usage. It would be difficult to explain here.

Answer (score 0):

Read about:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

And you should get something like this:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entrible, polymorphic: true
end

class UserTypeA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries, as: :entrible
end

class UserTypeB < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries, as: :entrible
end
```